# rvm install via capistrano is flooding output

Tags: bash, shell, rvm, capistrano

I'm running a shell script via capistrano to install rvm and ruby. When running

```
rvm install ruby-${RUBY_VERSION} 2>&1 > ../log/ruby_install.log
```

in my script, all output seems to be going to the log file, except for the scrollbar output. that output is being sent back to capistrano and it's flooding the output, and looks horrible.

Is there any way I can hide the progress during the command?

I tried running

```
alias curl="curl --silent"
```

before the command, but it doesn't work at all, so I guess the install is happening via some other means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @mpapis lead me to the following solution:

```
# Rename .curlrc if present
if [[ -f $HOME/.curlrc ]]; then
    echo "Backing up .curlrc"
    mv $HOME/.curlrc $HOME/.curlrc~
fi

# Create a temporary .curlrc configuration file, this prevents curl from flooding the Capistrano output
{
    echo "insecure"
    echo "silent" # Hide verbose output, it floods the capistrano output
    echo "show-error"
} > $HOME/.curlrc
```

I added the above snippet to my bash script, and at the end, I just restored .curlrc to it's previous state:

```
rm $HOME/.curlrc
if [[ -f $HOME/.curlrc~ ]]; then
    mv $HOME/.curlrc~ $HOME/.curlrc
fi
```

This is modified from rvm-capistrano, check it out on the original [Github Repository](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano/blob/master/lib/rvm/capistrano.rb#L124).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
gem install rvm-capistrano -v ">=1.3.0.rc11"
```

It contains code to make curl silent

Comment: Are you referring to this: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano/blob/master/lib/rvm/capistrano.rb#L124

Comment: I'm not using rvm-capistrano, but this snippet definitely helps.

Comment: you should try rvm-capistrano - I push there a lot of goodies like mixing RVM and non RVM servers

Comment: @mpapis I'm using rvm-capistrano 1.5.1 and I'm still getting the progress indicator flooding the capistrano output